# kendo combobox required validation not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, validation, kendo-ui

I have a kendo combobox given below. I want to validate if item are selected or not on a button click.

```
 $("#reason").kendoComboBox({
            placeholder: "Select Reason...",
            dataTextField: "Reason",
            dataValueField: "ID",
            change: function (e) {
                if (this.selectedIndex == -1) {
                    this.text("Select Reason...");
                }
            },
            filter: "contains",
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                serverFiltering: false,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "api/fastcart/GetAllReason",
                    }
                }
            },

        }).data("kendoComboBox");
```

Below is the button click method

```
 function cancelWithReason() {

       }
```

Can anyone knows how to validate the comobox using kendo validator?

Comment: Share your full code with html so we can get better idea

Comment: What does Kendo Validator have to do with the jQuery Validate plugin?   Edited tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below code to validate Kendo combobox with kendo validator

```
$("#cancelWithReason").click(function() {
      if (validatable.validate()) {
        messages.prepend("<li style='color:green'>validation passed</li>");
    } else {
        messages.prepend("<li style='color:red'>validation failed</li>");   
    }
});
```

and for more detail, you can look in [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/krustev/ws3fp/)